# No call to CWinThread:ExitInstance

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mfc

In my  dialog based application, in `CWinApp::InitInstance` I create class that has framed window `v1`:

**creating modHolder**

```
CWinThread* pThread= AfxBeginThread(RUNTIME_CLASS(modHolder));
```

**declaring modHolder**

```
class modHolder : public CWinThread
{
    DECLARE_DYNCREATE(modHolder)

protected:
    modHolder();           // protected constructor used by dynamic creation
    virtual ~modHolder();

public:
    CMainWindow * v1;
    virtual BOOL InitInstance();
    virtual int ExitInstance();

protected:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};
```

During application close I expect to get call to `modHolder::ExitInstance()`

Unfortunately I have no this function. What might be problem? I think, that `CWinThread modHolder` should terminate automatically. Am I wrong?

Comment: It will terminate automatically, but not necessarily tidily. Unless you provide a synchronisation mechanism to force a tidy close, you won't see `ExitInstance` called. Also, if you have overridden `Run`, you also won't see it unles you call it in your override. For a UI thread, you need to call `PostQuitMessage` to exit tidily.

Answer (score 0):

CWinThread::ExitInstance is called when CWinThread::Run finishes.

You have the source code!